# How to verify the user is still logged in when getting a push notification?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I want to make sure that if a user logs out, or if they clear their cookies, they don't continue to receive push notifications (which might have private information).

I can't just destroy the push when users log out, or clearing the cookies wont stop them from coming in.

I thought I could set a cookie with the user's ID when they logged in and cleared it when they logged out, then send it along with every push and check if it matches the cookie, but apparently you can't check cookies or other local storage from a service worker.

Are there any other options? Surely this is something many websites would need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just coding a whole thing to keep track of the user session in the service worker using local storage. I'm posting it here in case someone else has this problem and finds my question:

This implementation requires:

- [idb-keyval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb-keyval) to be included in the service worker, though you can probably do something else.
- a url on your server that you can request which returns an identifying value for the user (like their database id)

Basically it fetches the user id from the server, and stores it (and the time it was saved). When you get a push, you can get the latest ID (which it will update if it has expired) which you can then compare to an id that you include in your push notifications. You can also call verify to update the latest state, which I do upon activation, as well as loading /login or /logout.

here is my code:

```
//paste in code from https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval/blob/master/dist/idb-keyval-iife.min.js
const USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION = 60; //minutes

//wait for push event
self.addEventListener('push', e=> {
    var data = e.data.json();

    //get currently stored session id
    verifySessionUser().then(sessionUserId => {
        if (!sessionUserId) console.log('sessionUserId not found (somehow....)');
        console.log('sessionUserId - stored:',sessionUserId,'| push:',data.data.userId,'| =',sessionUserId==data.data.userId);

        //if id passed from push matches stored ID
        if (sessionUserId != data.data.userId) return console.log('stored session ID does not match push id, not displaying push');

        //show push notifiation to user
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
            body: data.body,
            icon: data.image,
            badge: '/images/badge.png',
            data: data.data,
        });

    });
});


//catche failed requests and displays the offline page when necessary
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    e.respondWith(
        //attempt to request page from server
        fetch(e.request)
            //request was successful
            .then((response) => {

                //check if the logout url was requested
                if (e.request.url.includes('example.com/logout')) {
                    console.log('SW - user logged out, clearing saved session user');
                    idbKeyval.del('currentUserSession');
                }

                //check if the url was a login auth url (the user just logged in)
                else if (e.request.url.includes('example.com/login')) {
                    console.log('SW - user logged in, updating session user');
                    verifySessionUser();
                }

                return response;
            })
    );
});

//new service worker installed
self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    console.log('SW - ACTIVATED ');

    verifySessionUser();
});

//checks for a valid current session id - updates it if not, rejects if new session is invalid
function verifySessionUser () {
    console.log('SW - verifying session user');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //attempt to get the current session user
        getSessionUser()
            //success - the session id is valid and up to date
            .then(userId => resolve(userId))
            //error - getting it failed, we should update it
            .catch(currentSessionStatus => {
                console.log('SW - session invalid: '+currentSessionStatus);
                updateSessionUser()
                    .then((freshSessionUserId) => resolve(freshSessionUserId))
                    .catch(err => reject(err));
            });
    });
}

//tries to get the currently stored session user; rejects if it's expired or empty
function getSessionUser () {
    console.log('SW - reading stored session user');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //check if the session has expired
        idbKeyval.get('lastUserSessionUpdate').then(lastUpdate=>{
            if (!lastUpdate)
                var minutesSinceLastUpdate;
            else
                var minutesSinceLastUpdate = Math.floor((new Date() - lastUpdate) / 1000 / 60);
            //console.log('minutes',minutesSinceLastUpdate,(new Date() - lastUpdate),USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION,minutesSinceLastUpdate > USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION);

            //check if session has expired
            if (minutesSinceLastUpdate >= USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION) {
                console.log('session has expired',minutesSinceLastUpdate ,'>=', USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION,minutesSinceLastUpdate >= USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION);
                return reject('expired');
            }

            //get currently stored session id
            idbKeyval.get('currentUserSession').then(sessionUserId => {
                if (!sessionUserId) return reject('empty');

                //success
                return resolve(sessionUserId);
            });

        });
    });
}

function updateSessionUser () {
    console.log('SW - updating session user');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //fetch session user id from server
        fetch('/user/session').then((e) => {

            //the request failed, most liked returned 404 because the user isn't logged in, so delete the saved session info if we have it
            if (!e.ok) {
                console.log('SW - session request failed',e);
                idbKeyval.del('currentUserSession');
                return reject('request failed');
            }

            //get text value of page (wow we need a whole function to do this? idiots.)
            e.text().then(text => {
                if (text.length != 24) {
                    console.log('SW - invalid session id returned',text,text.length);
                    idbKeyval.del('currentUserSession');
                    return reject('invalid length');
                }

                //success - save value to local storage
                idbKeyval.set('currentUserSession',text);
                idbKeyval.set('lastUserSessionUpdate',new Date());
                console.log('SW - updated session',text);
                return resolve(text);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

there may be a few uncaught promises, but only where they don't need to be caught.

Answer (score 0):

So the service worker cannot access the cookie store, at least I don't think it can. I don't use them anyway, so there's that.

Instead I use token based authentication. It is more robust and safer, etc. blah blah blah.

I persist the tokens in IndexedDB, which the service worker does have access to. So, when a notification is received you could check for the presence of a valid token and only show the notification when that token criteria is met.

You could also remove their push registration at that point, since that is managed in the service worker. Don't forget to send the unsubscribe to your server when this happens.

Comment: When do you set / clear this token? Where does it get the token from?

Comment: I built everything in AWS, so I use Cognito. The token is supplied when the user successfully authenticates with your identity service (Cognito, Auth0, etc.). They will supply you with a JWT. There are 3 parts to that. I store each one in IDB. 
They eventually time out and you can refresh authentication, etc. Far more than this thread will allow to cover here :)